# Connection Forcibly Closed Error with 32 bit COM Component call

Tags: c#, web-services, com, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a .asmx web service in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008  which is calling a class library method. The class library method is making a call to a third party COM compoment which is build over a 32 bit machine.

My web server is a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition. I have deployed this web service over IIS version 8.5 on this server.

When I first accessed this web service, I was thrown a COM Exception as below:

> Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {some GUID} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

As a resolution of this error, I made some changes in Application Pool settings in IIS. I went to Advanced settings of the related Application Pool in IIS and Set Enable 32 Bit Applications property to false.
Then I restarted the application pool and IIS.

Again when I accessed the web service trough debugging a Unit test, this time I didn't encounter above error, but the debugger gets crashed and thrown a error message in unit test as follows:

> Test method ABC threw exception:  System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: > An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost/MyService/MyServices.asmx. This could be due to the service > endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an 
>   HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service > shutting down). See server logs for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected > error occurred on a receive. --->  System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data > from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by > the remote host. --->  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing 
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I also noticed the Administrative Events Log. and I could see one error at random times:

> A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process > id was '3580'. The data field contains the error number.

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. You state:

> which is build over a 32 bit machine.

and

> and Set Enable 32 Bit Applications property to false.

Change that setting back to `True`. Your COM DLL is most likely a 32-bit binary. You won't be able to load 32-bit binaries into a 64-bit process.

Secondly the error code `80040154` means that your COM library hasn't been registered. To do this open a command line window (you need to "Run As Adminstrator"):

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe  <path_to_DLL>
```

For example:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe "c:\program files (x86)\MyApp\MyLib.dll"
```

Comment: Still no luck. I have Enabled 32 bit applications and set it to true. I also got it registered through regsvr32. I am still getting following exception .Test method ABC threw exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: > An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/MyService/MyServices.asmx. This could be due to the service > endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service > shutting down). See server logs for more details. --->

Comment: @SachinPuri - without seeing your code, config etc I can't really help much further.

Comment: I can provide you whatever details. you need